# PHP/MySQL syntax error while trying to insert a couple values

Tags: php, mysql

How can I fix this line in PHP/MySQL? The server returns the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id', 'title', 'yes', 'no') VALUES (2,test, 0, 0)' at line 1
```

for the line

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO things('id', 'title', 'yes', 'no') VALUES ($counter,$thing, 0, 0);", $con);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO things (`id`, `title`, `yes`, `no`) VALUES ($counter,$thing, 0, 0);"
```

Use ticks and not single quotes. Also, you are not quoting your string there. You should do proper sanitization.

You should switch to PDO or mysqli. mysql_ functions are deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to fix that problem. But now it's saying `Unknown column 'testtest' in 'field list'` where testtest is $thing.

Comment: right because you don't quote your string. ($counter,'$thing', 0, 0) would technically work but you really should do proper sanitizing through built in mysqli or PDO functions. Any tutorial on the two will show you how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around $counter and $thing

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO things('id', 'title', 'yes', 'no') 
VALUES ('$counter','$thing', 0, 0);", $con);
```